# Conditional Formatting via VBA MS Access Report not working

Tags: ms-access, report

I am having a trouble while trying to conditionally format the exhibition of records in a report inside a MS Access 2007 form.

I have search the Internet and I have seen lots os fellows stating that it is possible to perform visual changes in a single record via code implementing the method Detail_Paint() for the event Paint of the Detail section in a Report. Those people say that something like this is going to work:

```
Private Sub Detail_Paint()
    val = CStr(Me.someTextBox.Value)
    If val = "constraint" Then
        Me.lineStrikethrough.BorderStyle = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that although the reading statement *Me.someTextBox.Value* returns the value of each record when the Paint event is thrown, the writing statement *Me.lineStrikethrough.BorderStyle = 0* writes the value of the property BorderStyle for **every single** line in my report, not only for the one respecting the single record whose value I read from *someTextBox* field.

Can anyone tell me why such is happening? If this is the correct behaviour (although it does not seem right to me), how can I achieve my goal?

Note: *lineStrikethrough* is used to perform a strikethrough effect over the record in a Report. If there is another way to do that I would be happy to know.

Comment: What is `num`? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: Hi @MarkC. It was a typo. `num` is the actually `val`. But don´t worry, the running version of my code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1 - Use the Detail's On Print event and not On Paint event.

```
Private Sub Detail_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
    val = CStr(Me.someTextBox.Value)
    If val = "constraint" Then
        Me.lineStrikethrough.BorderStyle = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

2 - To see the conditional formatting, always open your report in Print Preview and not Report View.

Comment: Is there a way to see a report in Print view while it is inside a form?

Comment: I don't believe so since in Print Preview mode, pages align to print settings (margins, size, portrait/landscape) and is exportable to other formats with a conditional ribbon tab. Why not have a command button that triggers the report in print preview: `DoCmd.OpenReport "rptName", acViewPreview`?

Comment: unfortunately the customer I work for wishes the form be presented this way, with the report inside the form for listing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You are really close!!  :-)  In my testing, it appears that the `Detail_Paint()` event allows you to change the formatting of controls, but changes ***will continue in subsequent records*** until you change/reset them to something else.

In your code sample, you just need to add another line to turn the strikethrough `BorderStyle` back on when the condition is no longer met.

```
Private Sub Detail_Paint()
    Val = CStr(Me.someTextBox.Value)
    If Val = "constraint" Then
        Me.lineStrikethrough.BorderStyle = 0
    Else
        Me.lineStrikethrough.BorderStyle = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

I found this clue on a [code sample on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836875.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which demonstrates conditional formatting using the `Detail_Paint()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Select Case to work best in the detail paint over if statements for a continuous form.

'Private Sub Detail_Paint()

```
Select Case CStr(Me.someTextBox.Value)

    Case "constraint"
        Me.lineStrikethrough.BorderStyle = 0

    Case Else
        Me.lineStrikethrough.BorderStyle = 1 'or what the default value is

End Select
```